# How do I randomly jumble a string imploded by ',' in PHP (ex: a,b,c = c,b,a) in a oneliner?

Tags: php, arrays, string, variables, implode

How do I randomly jumble a string imploded by ',' in PHP (ex: a,b,c = c,b,a) in a one-liner?

Here is an example

```
srand((double)microtime*1000000);
$foo=array(
  a => "a",
  b => "b",
  c => "c");
echo "The jumbled comma separated values are: ".randomlyjumble(.implode(",",$foo))."<br />";
```

Comment: Write your own function so when you call it, it will always be an one-line [one-wordie actually].

Comment: What should happen to the array keys?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`shuffle`](https://www.php.net/shuffle) before imploding. Do keep in mind that `shuffle` takes its parameter by reference for inline modification, so you need to do it on a separate line.

Answer (score 0):

If the array contents only contains characters of length 1 you may use the following:

```
$foo=array('a', 'b', 'c');
echo implode(',', str_split(str_shuffle(implode('', $foo)),1));
```

If the length of the characters is >1 then you need to use shuffle, and here a cryptic workaround to use it in one line:

```
echo 'hello '.implode(',',array_map(function($w)use(&$foo){shuffle($w);return $w;}, array_map(function($v)use(&$foo){return array($foo);}, $foo)[0])[0]).' world';
```

Note that you need **PHP 5.4+** to  be able to do this.

The uncompressed form:

```
echo 'hello '.
    implode(',',
        array_map(function($w)use(&$foo){
            shuffle($w);
            return $w;
        },
            array_map(function($v)use(&$foo){
                return array($foo);
            }, $foo)
        [0])[0]
        )
    .' world';
```

The best way is to create a function for this like @moonwave99 said in the comments:

```
echo implode(',', array_random_sort($foo));
function array_random_sort($v){shuffle($v);return($v);}
```

Comment: What's php 5.4 specific here?

Comment: @zerkms somethine like this `array_map(function($v)use(&$foo){return array($foo);}, $foo)[0]` is PHP 5.4 specific, a simple example: `echo explode(',', '1,2')[0];`.

Comment: @HamZa DzCyberDeV: oops, I didn't notice you're dereferencing arrays